# "fatal error" when running simple Qt Quick Project on Android?

Tags: android, qt, qml

I just started using Necessitas Qt and I'm trying to run a test program on my Galaxy Tab

It didn't work, there's an error showing "Your application encountered a fatal error and cannot continue."

Then I tried to run an empty qml with just "Hello World" on it, it still gives me the same error.

I tried to create a widget this time with just a button, and it loaded safely

I need some help on how to track what's the error, what settings do I need to check on my Necessitas and Galaxy to make it work?

I've always used Qt Quick Project on project creation and I didn't touch the .pro and main.cpp yet cause Im still studying that part.

Thanks

Comment: I thought Necessitas didn't work with Qt Quick.

Comment: I googled after your comment, and came up with this http://www.slideshare.net/snowpong/targeting-android-with-qt so im quite sure it works

Comment: My leader found it, the problem was on the qmlapplicationviewer.cpp